# Hide images from third party app

Tags: jquery, html, css, web-services

I am rendering third party application in my page. I have integrated third party app in my application with webservices. I am not controlling its functionality or look and feel.

Third party application have list of applications which are rendered in my page as columns: Icon of App (Logo-Image), Name, Description, login.

I want to customize the look and feel of the page say I want to hide the image and change font.

I tried with CSS override but somehow I am unable to do it. I know it might be easy but not an expert in CSS or UI stuff.

Comment: It renders list of application in my page i.e. list of apps such as Facebook, Linkedin, Instagram etc. User can click login and access their apps. I was testing it with CSS: img{ display:none !important; }

Comment: It may be rendering an iframe which is why you're not seeing the style changes when you add CSS. In which case need to inject stylesheet or individual styles into the iframe. Without a view of the code though, it's just speculation.